# What's a good setup for integrating magit with evil mode?

Tags: magit, evil

I'm trying to set up magit to work nicely with evil mode. Ideally I'd be able to open the `magit-status-mode` buffer in normal mode and be able to stage/commit from that buffer with vim-like keybindings.

To open `magit-status` in normal mode, I have the following:

```el
(evil-set-initial-state 'magit-status-mode 'normal)
(evil-define-key 'normal magit-status-mode-map
  "j" 'magit-goto-next-section
  "k" 'magit-goto-previous-section)
```

Is there a way to add keybindings to this map for staging/committing files?    Or a better way to accomplish my stated goal above than this approach altogether?

Comment: Not an evil user myself, but have you looked at https://github.com/justbur/evil-magit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`evil-magit`](https://github.com/justbur/evil-magit) is certainly a good choice. It is well maintained.